# Extracting with subfolders but without parent folders

Tags: unzip, zip, 7zip

I have a zipfile structured like this:

```
- root
  - subfolder
    - subsubfolder
      - file1
      - file2
    - file3
    - file4
```

Using 7zip, I would like to extract the archive in such a way, that the resulting structure is:

```
- subsubfolder
  - file1
  - file2
- file3
- file4
```

My problem is, that neither `7z e` nor `7z x` accomplish this. When I use

`7z x archive.zip root/subfolder`

the structure doesn't change, as the files retain their full paths, and when I use

`7z e archive.zip root/subfolder`

the files retain no path at all, leaving me with a flat structure an an empty `subsubfolder`.

**Edit**: Unzip or any other kind of zip-tool I can use in Linux would also be fine.

Comment: Should this goto superuser?

Comment: I am having the same issue, via the 7Zip UI, drilling down to a subfolder and extracting it to a destination folder does not persist the parent path (which is the desired operation). Unfortunately at this time it appears there is no commandline option to do the same.